# Money-rails gem: How to use Money object in ActiveRecord query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, currency, money-rails

Before I installed the `money-rails` gem, I had this query in my controller:

```
@forecasts.where('max >= ?', @budget).limit(1)[0]
```

where `:budget` was an integer column in table `forecasts`.

After installing `money-rails` I renamed that column to `:budget_subunits`, entered `monetize: :budget_subunits as: :budget` in my `:forecast` model so that `:budget` is now a Money object.  Now this query results in the following error:

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "--- !ruby/object:Money fractional: 4000000000.0 currency: !ruby/object:Money::Currency id: :usd priority: 1 iso_code: USD name: United States Dollar symbol: $ alternate_symbols: - US$ subunit: Cent subunit_to_unit: 100 symbol_first: true html_entity: $ decimal_mark: . thousands_separator: ',' iso_numeric: '840' bank: !ruby/object:Money::Bank::VariableExchange rounding_method: rates: {} mutex: !ruby/object:Mutex {} " LINE 1: ...get_segments"."budget_source_id" = $1 AND (max >= '--- !ruby... ^ : SELECT "budget_segments".* FROM "budget_segments" WHERE "budget_segments"."budget_source_id" = $1 AND (max >= '--- !ruby/object:Money fractional: 4000000000.0 currency: !ruby/object:Money::Currency id: :usd priority: 1 iso_code: USD name: United States Dollar symbol: $ alternate_symbols: - US$ subunit: Cent subunit_to_unit: 100 symbol_first: true html_entity: $ decimal_mark: . thousands_separator: '','' iso_numeric: ''840'' bank: !ruby/object:Money::Bank::VariableExchange rounding_method: rates: {} mutex: !ruby/object:Mutex {} ') ORDER BY "budget_segments".max ASC LIMIT 1
```

I know I can just use the `:budget_subunits` column and compare that to the `:max_subunits` column, but wouldn't that defeat the whole purpose of using the money-rails gem?

Simply put, how can I use a Money object in activerecord queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `cents` on it to convert it into its cents value, and query on that.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I understand I can do that, but I felt like that defeated a big purpose of the money gem, which I thought was to seamlessly use the money object without subunits and having the gem convert it to subunits when it hits the database, and then auto-converting it back for the output.  But if that's the only way to use it then I will.

Comment: No, the Money gem won't magically convert things for you. No gem should.